# How to add one to many relationship using IdentityUser as many to another entity using as one in webapi dotnet 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

how to do one to many relationship 
between User:IdentityUser
as many users to one  UserClass

i try this

```
    public class UserClass
{
    public int UserClassId  { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }

}

    public class User : IdentityUser<int>
{

    public int UserClassId { get; set; }
    public UserClass UserClass { get; set; }
```

}

and try Fluent API like this

```
       builder.Entity<UserClass>()
            .HasMany<User>(u=>u.Users)
            .WithOne(p=>p.UserClass)
            .HasForeignKey(p=>p.UserClassId);
```

the same dosn't work and thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing I would recommend is to name your `User` class `ApplicationUser` as it is the recommended practice when extending the `IdentityUser` model. This naming standard can help prevent naming conflicts that may arise as your application grows. I will reference your `User` class as `ApplicationUser` in this answer and example code. Also, I am assuming you are using Entity Framework Core in this scenario. If you are using another ORM then your mileage may vary.

There are a couple of ways to define the many-to-one relationship between `UserClass` and `ApplicationUser`. The simplest solution is creating a fully defined relationship, which is basically what you've already done.

```cs
public class UserClass 
{
    public int UserClassId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int> 
{
    public int UserClassId { get; set; }
    public UserClass UserClass { get; set; }
}
```

In this example we've defined the foreign key on the `ApplicationUser` class as well as defined the public `UserClass` property on it. One change I did make was removing the virtual modifier from the users enumerable on your `UserClass` model. In EF Core, virtual collections are used for lazy-loading and require extra configuration in order to work properly. If that is something you specifically require then I recommend reading more about it in the EF Core docs. I also used `IEnumerable` for the collections but you can determine what works best for you.

EF Core should be able to automatically configure the relationship as long as it is properly defined and uses the correct naming conventions. In order to manually configure it, I'll put the code below. Generally I like to just go ahead and manually configure relationships regardless of whether EF Core is able to do it automatically.

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
        .HasOne(p => p.UserClass)
        .WithMany(b => b.ApplicationUsers);
}
```

You can also manually configure the foreign key as such along with constraint values.

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
        .HasOne(p => p.UserClass)
        .WithMany(b => b.ApplicationUsers)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasForeignKey(p => p.UserClassId);
}
```

You should only have to define the relationship one way, in this case from the `ApplicationUser` side, for EF Core to pick it up. If not, you can read the docs for recommended solutions. Link below to EF Core documentation regarding relationships.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key

Edit : Add constraint configuration example.

Comment: First thanks my dear it's added when i try to add in table in database i get this error     Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update[10000]
      An exception occurred in the database while saving changes for context type 'MyGroupAPI.Data.DataContext'.
      Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
       ---> Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 19: 'FOREIGN KEY constraint failed'.

Comment: @mohamedhemeda Sounds like you may have to define a foreign key constraint for the relationship. You'll have to configure if the relationship is required and what delete behavior to use. I will update my example with the additional configuration values. Here is a link to the docs covering this specific topic. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#required-and-optional-relationships

Comment: @mohamedhemeda You can reference the example I edited with the additional constraint configuration. Be careful with what `OnDelete` behavior you choose to use. I used the default Cascade behavior in my example. This will cause related `ApplicationUser` entities to be deleted if their `UserClass` is deleted. You may not want this behavior in your application, so read about the various options. Also remember to update your migrations !

Comment: really thanks but still the same error when try to add data on user table also when i change isRequired(false); iam using sqlite

Comment: @mohamedhemeda I think the issue is the limitations of the EF Core SQLite provider. If you have to use SQLite, there are some workarounds for limitations. I'd recommend looking into getting a free Azure or AWS account so you can setup a free tier cloud SQL database. Gives you much more flexibility when developing your apps. Here's a link to the SQLite workarounds. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sqlite/limitations#modeling-limitations